Logrotation and new entries with timestamps from already rotated file
I have a file, metrics.log, that gets log rotated daily at 23:59 via log4j's RollingFileAppender. The log rotated file is kept in another directory as metrics-$DATE.log.
It contains JSON-formatted log data (also, a timestamp from when the log line originated). Exactly each minute, a new log line gets written into metrics.log.
We recently found out that many log lines appear around 7am in the morning at once. To further investigate the source of the problem, I added more timestamps.
The setup is as such:

Elastic/Kibana running in Docker on an Ubuntu machine.
Logstash and metrics.log on a Windows machine.

I added a 'received' timestamp, for when a log line is received by Logstash on the Windows machine (via a Ruby filter in the pipeline code => "event.set('received', Time.now.utc)"). When Elastic receives the line, I also added an ingest pipeline that adds a 'delivered' timestamp.
Those two timestamps are always next to each other, so I guess this part of the ELK stack is okay.
But the timestamp of the line in metrics.log sometimes is hours or days apart.
I can search for those mismatched entries by executing a POST /logs-metrics-prod/_search with following command
"doc['delivered'].value.getMillis() - doc['timestamp'].value.getMillis() > 10000"

and the results are like:
{
    "hits": [
      {
          [..]
          "@timestamp": "2024-08-01T22:00:08.515Z",
          "received": "2024-08-02T06:48:55.932Z",
          "delivered": "2024-08-02T06:48:56.470630659Z",
          "timestamp": "2024-08-01T22:00:08.515Z"
        }
      },
      [..]

At 2024-08-02T06:48:55.933Z the metrics.log is rotated (23:59) and can't contain a "@timestamp": "2024-08-01T22:01:08.519Z".
The pipeline configuration is as such:
input {
  file {
    path => ["C:/wms/metrics.log"]
    start_position => "beginning"
    mode => "tail"
    codec => plain { charset => "ISO-8859-1" }
  }
}

filter {
  date {
    match => ["timestamp", "ISO8601"]
    timezone => "Europe/Berlin"
    target => "@timestamp"
  }
  ruby {
   # format: 2024-07-25T06:52:59.493Z
   code => "event.set('received', Time.now.utc)"
  }
  mutate {
    copy => { "@timestamp" => "timestamp" }
    [..]
  }
[..]

I copy timestamp around because the metrics.log are emitting in local time and not UTC.
A log line in raw looks like that:
{"timestamp":"2024-08-05T00:12:12.379774800","type":"metric","offenePickauftraege":{"PUPT":0,"GTHY":0},"anzahlPicker":{"PUPT":0,"GTHY":0}}

I think i now tried all permutations of start_position => "beginning/end" and mode => "tail/read".
Also, I can't find anything of interest in the Logstash log files (even on Loglevel INFO).
Between each attempt, I delete the logs-metrics-prod data stream and restart Logstash to have a clean 'restart', let it run through the day and take a look again at the next morning.
So, can it be a problem with the log rotation? Any other idea or hint where to look next as I'm out of ideas. Unfortunately, changing the program that emits the logs/log rotation into unique file names etc. is not possible.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

Trimmed code for better readability.
